# KeystoneJS | How to create only fields on admin area?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, keystonejs

I need manage some variables on admin page, like: Title, Some url, text. But i don't know, how to create new **List** to manage them.

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

/**
 * Home section Model
 * =============
 */

var Home = new keystone.List('Home', {
});

Home.add({
    mainTitle: { type: String },
    mainSubtitle: { type: String },
    videoImage: { type: Types.CloudinaryImage },
    videoSrc: { type: String }
});

Home.register();
```

[image]
This code created simple list with '**Add**' function, but i need something like this, to manage my general settings:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What sorts of settings are you trying to manage? Do they apply to your entire site, or are they settings for something else? Why are you storing these settings in a database versus having them exist server-side? And which version of Keystone are you using? Looks like 4 but the interface for adding a document looks different.

Comment: @SheaBelsky v.0.3.17. I need singleton instead collection. I have SPA and need to manage page content. Yes, they apply to my entire site.